# where to find the Oauth token and secret in the linkedin application

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I am trying to practice the examples in the book "mining the social web". Unlike the applications I had created in twitter and facebook, the Oauth token and secret in the linkedin never show up. I only see my `client ID` and `client secret`.

by the way, since I do not have any personal url, can someone explain to me what is the appropriate URL I should enter? In the twitter and facebook applications, I just randomly entered some URL, like www.twitter.com, and it worked. In this application for linkedin, I entered www.linkedin.com, but no Oauth token comes out.

I know this question is too basic for you guys, sorry for posting this. I did google the solution for a while, but it seems like no one has ever posted this question.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly get an `OAuth Token`. You have to follow the authentication procedure to receive an `OAuth Token`.

**Steps involved:**

1. Configure your LinkedIn application with a valid callback url which your server is listening to.
2. Request an Authorization Code
3. Exchange Authorization Code for a Request Token

This LinkedIn link will help you on what parameters to send in each request and the URL for the same.
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Comment: what is the url I should enter? I followed this link you provided, I entered like `https://www.linkedin.com` and `https://dev.example.com/auth/linkedin/callback`.
Then I am confused by the 2nd step, which requires me to direct the user's browser to linkedin's oauth 2.0 authorization endpoint. What is this?

Comment: It means that you should include a link (`https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization
`) on your  webpage which on clicking should hit linkedin authorization url. You need to send various parameters like `response_type`, `client_id`, `redirect_uri`, `state` and `scope` in the request by query parameters. So, sample request/ link would be `https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fauth%2Flinkedin&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile`