# Where to get USER_TOKEN & USER_SECRET for LinkedIn Scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I am trying just to access my own LinkedIn profile data.

Steps followed:

> - Setup a new application
> - Get CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET

But, where to get the USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET as mentioned here "You can simply use the 4 credentials that are provided to you in your LinkedIn application as part of an OAuth 1.0a flow and immediately access your data."? I've tried without it, and it doesn't work.

The code is given in under the **Developer Authentication** headline [here](https://github.com/DEKHTIARJonathan/python3-linkedin).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where to find the Oauth token and secret in the linkedin application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226310/where-to-find-the-oauth-token-and-secret-in-the-linkedin-application)

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth 1.0a flow has been deprecated by LinkedIn (https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates), so there is no way to get a user token and secret without going through the OAuth 2 flow described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/compliance/context